# What are second party leaders?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **second party leaders** in the following sentence?

> . Yet, the Likud plus these do not ensure that the figure of 61 can be reached and this is where Mr. Netanyahu is an issue. Parties led by second-rank leaders such as Yair Lapid, Benny Gantz or Gideon Sa’ar are opposed to him as he is the first Israeli Prime Minister on trial for three criminal cases — bribery, fraud and breach of trust.

I looked up the meaning of **second party leader** on google but didn't find anything.

Comment: Did you mean **second-rank leaders**?  "Second party leaders" does not appear in that quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q.

> **What are second party leaders?**

Actually in the text **second-rank leaders** is used not second party leaders and the meaning is different and more easily located in the dictionary.

---

**second-rank**,  means second tier or level. Second-tier is used to describe an **organization, etc. that is not among the biggest, most successful, or most important of its type:**

> **rank** noun [C/U] (POSITION) a position in relation to others higher or lower, showing the importance or authority of the person having it: Ref CED [**Rank**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rank)

> **tier** noun [ C ] one of several levels of importance, quality, etc.: Ref CED [**Tier**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tier)

> **second-tier** adjective [ before noun ] used to describe a product, organization, etc. that is not among the biggest, most successful, or most important of its type: Ref CED [**Second-tier**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/second-tier)